# Add class to dynamically generated HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm working to use custom checkbox styles with a checkbox which is dynamically generated by javascript for the Google Identity Toolkit. For example, we add this div:

```
<div id="gitkitWidgetDiv"></div>
```

And the Google Identity Toolkit script generates new html for that div.

I need to add a class to the HTML which is added by the javascript without any action by the user and I'm struggling to make it work. For example, here is my code:

```
$("#gitkitWidgetDiv").on('ready', ".gitkit-sign-in-options label", function() {
    $(this).addClass('checkbox');
});
```

I've tried switching 'ready' for a few other options and also using the livequery plugin, but nothing is working for me. It works if I use an active event like 'click,' but I can't figure out how to do this when the page loads. Could someone please help? Thanks!

Comment: Well, right after when you generate those elements, you can select them and apply the class, right ? Show us the code that creates the elements.

Comment: by dynamically you mean after user interaction? Or maybe you mean that you request it with some javascript code from an external service?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't control the code that generates the elements. It's added by www.gstatic.com/authtoolkit/js/gitkit.js.

Comment: Have you tried the load event instead of ready?

Comment: Do you have any docs of that library and checked for any event ?

Comment: Yes - the load event isn't successful.

Comment: I'm with @DontVoteMeDown - If this library generates new HTML, I'd usually expect they generate some sort of event, or a function that lets you add listeners. Might be worth briefly reading their documentation.

Comment: As far as I can tell there is no documentation with the type of details you are requesting. For example, here is the documentation for the UI: https://developers.google.com/identity-toolkit/v3/setup-frontend

Comment: would it be enough to use `#gitkitWidgetDiv .gitkit-sign-in-options label { ... }` instead of `.checkbox { ... }` in your custom stylesheet?

Comment: I tried that as well, but we're also using custom checkbox styles which are generated by a combination of CSS and javascript. I've already updated the styles accordingly, but javascript updates are necessary as well, and this is beyond my capabilities. This is why I'm asking if there is a way to add the class after everything loads.

Answer (score 0):

[Modern browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=mutationobserver) (including IE11) support [mutation obervers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver). You can use one to monitor the parent node of the div that will be added. When the div has been added, just add the class.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, I need to support IE 9 & 10.

Comment: I don't think that this can be the answer for now. We are trying to discover if the library has documentation and event listeners for that job. I'm saying because those observers reduces performance and must the last option.

Comment: I wonder whether it would be easier to work around the new CSS class, e.g by using more sophisticated CSS selectors or using 'live' events.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by live events. Could you provide more information?

Comment: See http://api.jquery.com/live/ (even if today this in done with on()). Basically you register an event handler for the target's parent, and in that handler you check whether the event target matches the element you want to monitor. This technique allows you to register event handlers for elements that do not exist yet.

Comment: Yes - that's what I was trying to use, but I'm struggling to put together a script that works with .on. Since .live has been deprecated, how do I persistently monitor something with .on? It seems like an action needs to occur in order to use .on - e.g. load, ready, click, mouseout, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Here's something I made which comes in handy in annoying cases like this where it's difficult to tell when the element  you need has finished loading in: https://gist.github.com/DanWebb/8b688b31492632b38aea

so after including the function it'd be something like:

```
var interval = 500,
    stopTime = 5000,
    loaded = false;
setIntervalTimeout(function() {
    if($('.dynanicElementClass').length && !loaded) {
       $('.dynanicElementClass').addClass('checkbox');
       loaded = true;
    }
}, interval, stopTime);
```

It's not perfect and I'm sure there are better solutions out there but in most cases like this it does the job.